# form_for ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments (3 for 1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My code is super simple, but I can't figure out where the error comes from. I'm accessing localhost:3000/clients/new and I got the error `wrong number of arguments (3 for 1)`

**Top of the stack trace**

```
ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments (3 for 1):
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:378:in `form_for'
  (gem) haml-3.1.8/lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:183:in `form_for_with_haml'
  (gem) haml-3.1.8/lib/haml/helpers/xss_mods.rb:132:in `form_for_with_haml_xss'
  app/views/clients/new.html.haml:1:in `_app_views_clients_new_html_haml__386962141__622328728'
```

**/app/controllers/clients_controller.rb**

```
class ClientsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @client = Client.new
  end
end
```

**/app/models/client.rb**

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
end
```

**/app/views/clients/new.html.haml**

```
= form_for @client, remote: true do |f|
  = f.text_field :name
  = f.submit
```

And if I inspect @client just one line before form_for, I got this:

```
=> #<Client id: nil, name: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Edited to simplify the code

Comment: what version of ruby are you running on?

Comment: ruby 1.9.3p327 (2012-11-10 revision 37606) [i686-linux]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, fixed. I post the answer even if it may not be useful for most of you, but I hope it may help some

Error came from the fact that I created a helper with a function named `fields_for`. Changing my function name to something different fixed the problem.

If someone could explain though:

Why my custom `fields_for` which is nested in my module takes precedence over the `fields_for` of actionpack?

And also why the stack trace stopped at the line `(gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:378` instead of showing the line where my `fields_for` is declared?